# How to do this angle background by CSS?

Tags: css, background, angle

[image]
How can I achieve to get something like this? Can you help me?

Comment: svg shapes or http://bennettfeely.com/clippy/

Comment: try editing your link to: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NJDw7.png

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve that with CSS.

The idea is to have 3 blocs :

1. a container (which will contain the image as background)
2. an empty block which will be rotated to simulate the triangle
3. a div wich will contain the text

The idea is to rotate the empty block to get the angle you need.
To create the "triangle" effect, we use the `overflow:hidden` on the container to act as a mask (you also need to make the rotated block bigger than hte container to cover it despite the rotation).

Then you define the triangle & content blocks positions & z-index to superpose them.

**Note :** You don't necessary have to put the image as the background of the container block. you can also display with an `img` tag and use z-index again to display the 3 blocks on top of each other.

```css
.container,
.rotated-block {
  display:block;
}

.container {
  background: #000000;
  width: 600px;
  height: 350px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.rotated-block {
  position: absolute;
  zi-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 150%;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  transform: rotate(-20deg);
  left: -40%;
  top: -7%;
}

.content {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 3;
  top: 35%;
  left: 10%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="content">
        <p>Purly made with HTML & CSS</p>
     </div>
  <div class="rotated-block"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use multiple background mixing  image + gradient:

```css
body {
  margin:0;
  background:linear-gradient(65deg, white 45%, transparent 45%), url(http://lorempixel.com/600/400/nature);
  background-size:auto auto, cover;
  }
/* demo makeup */
div {
  height:100vh;
  width:50%;
  display:flex;
  }
p {
  margin:auto;
  }
```

```html
<div><p>Whatever is on left</p></div>
```

---

*If the final idea is to have two different image, you may also take a look at mix-blend-mode and this demo http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/JRdEVO made for a similar question here ...*

---

### edit 2021

CSS shape are now well implemented and shape-outside could be usefull here :

example with CSS shape (clip-path/shape-poutside/shape-margin) and CSS calculation.

```css
.half-slant {
  display: flex;
}

.half-slant header {
  flex: 1;
  text-align: right;
  background: #ededed;
}

.half-slant header img {
  float: right;
  height: 100%;
  clip-path: polygon( calc(100% - 55vw) 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, calc(100% - 45vw) 100%);
  shape-outside: polygon( calc(100% - 55vw) 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, calc(100% - 45vw) 100%);
  shape-margin: 0.5em;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.half-slant h1 {
  margin-top: clamp(1em, 40vw, 8%);
}
```

```html
<section class="half-slant">
  <header>
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1001/1200/400">
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <p>some text below</p>
    <p>and more</p>
  </header>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an article that might help you out: https://www.viget.com/articles/angled-edges-with-css-masks-and-transforms